# insert into table implode array

Tags: php, mysql

i've got a var that is the *implode result* from a form...(i think its what it is called)
and i need to insert it on a table with other "fixed values"...

like this :

```
   $dx = $_POST['cid'];
  $vat = implode("', '", $dx);
```

also have

```
var1= $_SESSION['loginuser'];
var2= $_SESSION['formuser'];
```

and i need to insert in a table like this :
var1+var2+vat
 for each value in vat variable

i think i'm going to need to create another var from $dx imploding with just a coma but i'm also not shure if i'm correct...
and i'm lacking the code to do this can someone give me a hand?

OK i need the correct syntaxe code to insert the values into a table..

Something like:

for each value in $vat
insert into table_name (var1, var2, *vat*)....

Comment: please revise your post

Comment: revise ? what do you mean? sorry my english is not very good, but i didn't understand what you need me to do ...